# how do I use sapply() with Surv()?

Tags: r, sapply

I have the following:

```
splits<-split(df,disease)
```

where I have split a datframe by column1. But I want to use the Surv function:

```
library(survival)
with(df,Surv(TIME,STATUS)~GENDER)
```

How do I extend this to my split dataset to run the Surv() function separately on each split dataset? I have tried using the sapply() function:

```
surv.obj<-sapply(splits, function(x) Surv(TIME,STATUS)~GENDER)
```

which seems to work fine because I get:

```
surv.obj

$heart_disease
Surv(TIME,STATUS)~GENDER
<environment: 0X0000000000000019cac10>

$cancer
Surv(TIME,STATUS)~GENDER
<environment: 0X0000000000000019cac11>

.
.
.
```

, however when trying to use the survfit function: `survfit(surv.obj)`, I try to plot surv.obj$heart_disease I get

```
plot(suv.obj$heart_disease)
Error in Surv(TIME,STATUS) : object TIME not found
```

which clearly means the sapply statement has not done it's job. Could someone advise me what the correct sapply syntax should have been?

Comment: Where the `Surv` function comes from?

Comment: from the "survival" package

Comment: You probably should be using `surv.obj<-sapply(splits, function(x) survfit(Surv(TIME,STATUS)~GENDER, x))` to fit the same model on each subset of data. It doesn't make sense to just create a list of identical formulas with empty environments first

Comment: ok no problem - this makes sense. have just done this. how do I then split up each survival object (by disease)? I want multiple `surv.obj` i.e. `surv.obj.heart_disease` `surv.obj.cancer` etc etc.